# Class extend by jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, class, oop, extends

I need do change some method in jQuery UI datepicker but I dont wanna modify original code, so how my class can extends jquery ui and override some method?

```
function MyDatepicker() {
this.extend(jQuery); // extend jquery??

    this.datepicker.onclick = function () {
        alert("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: What method do you want to overwrite?